# powershell script execution from remote to local

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that starts the skype for business and sends message to a user. Currently the powershell script is on my local machine. What if the powershell script is deployed on server. I want it to access my local client and initiate the skype for business as there is no Skype for business installed on server. Also when the script is executed it should send message from my Skype client

Answer (score 0):

What is your question exactly ?
If I understand well, you want to put a script on a server in order for the clients to execute him.
When do you want clients to run the script ? At logon ?

I guess using a GPO and eventually running the script using an admin workstation account should do the trick.
If it works on your computer, you only need to check account and rights, and the way your clients should run the script.

Comment: The powershell will reside on server. When the clients login with application there is an option to start the chat. on clicking on the chat button on application should call the power shell. If the client machine has the skype for business signed in it will send the default message to a recipient. As the ps resides on the server how will it start the Skype for business residing on client

Comment: If the script is executed by the client machine, it will launch his Skype, not the server one, even if the script is located on the server.
Can't you build a developement environment ? It will help you a lot to test your script.